# Making bio metric attendance system using cheap android phone

Tags: android

I want a cheap Biometric system using any (cheap) Android mobile in which whoever presses the thumb, my android code should get authenticated callback with some unique person code(this is optional though).

But question is whether we can change the Android setting to allow storing of 100-500 people's finger prints?  Usually mobiles only allow upto 5 fingerprints to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

> my android code should get authenticated callback with some unique person code

Android does not support this. You only find out whether the user authenticated or not.

> whether we can change the Android setting to allow storing of 100-500 people's finger prints?

Android does not support this.

Comment: So it's clear that cheap Biometric system using any (cheap) Android mobile isn't feasible due to sensitive private data involved.

Comment: @user5858: You might be able to use a cheap Android device, but you would need an external fingerprint scanner that has an SDK that you can use that meets your needs. The on-board biometrics are not designed for your scenario.

Comment: Then face recognition can be implemented cheaply in Android phone without external devices I think

Comment: @user5858: Not if it is part of Android's biometric framework. Devices with some sort of proprietary face recognition APIs, or perhaps third-party face recognition libraries, might be able to do what you are seeking.

Comment: I meant to use cheap Android mobile for bio metric attendance. I guess I can collect face samples which will be stored on remote server with Opencv based face recognition technology. Only a small cheap Android mobile hardware can be sufficient -- that can be exciting.